# Zabbix error when browsing: "Configuration file error DB type "MYSQL" is not supported by current setup."

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, zabbix, mariasql

This happened after I upgraded the server from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.

Mysql service is running, I can connect to the zabbix DB with the mysql account in the zabbix conf files and show tables and info inside of those tables.

The error in zabbix_server.log is:

> [Z3001] connection to database 'zabbix' failed: [2002] Can't connect
>   to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
>   (2)"

```
ls -l /var/run/mysqld/
total 4
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 5 Jan 12 10:42 mysqld.pid
srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 0 Jan 12 10:42 mysqld.sock
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have socket specified in the Zabbix server configuration file? If yes, try commenting it out and restarting Zabbix server. Also try restarting Zabbix server if you have not done so since this error started appearing.

Answer (score 0):

You configure zabbix_server.conf ? 
Check this parameters:

- DBPassword
- DBName
- DBHost
- DBUser

Source: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/pt/manual/appendix/config/zabbix_server